# Python PIL - how to compare two images

Tags: python, image, compare, python-imaging-library

Okay, so I have 2 images:

[image: image1]

and

[image: image2]

and I want to compare them

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops
im1 = Image.open('im1.png')
im2= Image.open('im2.png')

def compare(im1, im2):
    #blah blah blah
```

Basically the 2 images are practically the same but 1 is larger and the other is smaller, so one has more pixels and the other has less pixels. I want a function that compares the 2 images and, for example, expresses the difference in numbers. If the number is small, I know the difference is almost non-existent, but if the number is large, they are different.

Or any other function that compares images. If you want use these 2 images, which I have used, so the result will be the same. Thanks

Comment: UPDATE: I found a way to compare the 2 numbers - I evaluate the number of black pixels of each image so I know that if one image has 14 black pixels and the other has 14 black pixels, they are the same. However, I have a problem if 2 different numbers have the same number of black pixels.

This is the best I can do. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just subtract the values of the images after reshaping OR cropping them:

```
img1 = img1.reshape(100, 200)
img2 = img2.reshape(100, 200)
# Calculate the absolute difference on each channel separately
dif = np.fabs(np.subtract(img2[:], img1[:]))
```

If you want to see the difference visually you could create a heatmap of the difference between the two images.

```
#Show image
imgplot = plt.imshow(dif)
# Choose a color palette
imgplot.set_cmap('jet')
plt.axis('off')
pylab.show()
```

Comment: "np" is numpy and "plt" is matplotlib?